# How to use pithos to store video files into cassandraDB and the data is replicated into another node in another machine

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-2.1

Currently, I have 2 different PC running ubuntu 16.04, and both pc have cassandra node that is listening to each other and replicating data.

I came across http://pithos.io and found out that it helps to store video files into cassandraDB(I'm not very sure how).

After looking at its documentation I'm still unsure on how exactly I can use pithos to store video.

Looking for any sample code or existing GitHub project that uses pithos to store videos into cassandraDB and the video data will be replicated into another node in another PC.

Many thanks to anyone who can help me

Comment: Data replication in Cassandra is standard functionality that doesn't require special code or something like. I recommend to read Cassandra documentation to understand how replication happens, how to setup replication factor correctly, etc. Online courses on DataStax Academy could be very helpful: https://academy.datastax.com/

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt, Thank you for the advice! I'll take a look in that link! (: